# How to configure stomp protocal when using stomp.js in client?

Tags: websocket, activemq-classic, stomp

Below is the web client example code I googled from https://dzone.com/articles/easy-messaging-stomp-over.

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
 var client = Stomp.client( "ws://localhost:61614/stomp", "v11.stomp" );    
 client.connect( "", "",    
  function() {
      client.subscribe("jms.topic.test",    
       function( message ) {                   
           alert( message );    
        }, { priority: 9 }     
      );
   client.send("jms.topic.test", { priority: 9 }, "Pub/Sub over STOMP!");
  }    
 );

</script>
```

My question is why connecting activemq with 'ws://localhost:61614/stomp' not 'stomp://localhost:61614/stomp'? What's the difference between below protocols in activemq.xml?

```
<transportConnectors>
        <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613"/>
        <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'ws' based transport connectors are for clients that want to connect via STOMP over WebSockets.  WebSockets is a different way of communicating that a straight up TCP based socket to the STOMP based transport connector and requires a different handshake amongst other things and are often used inside a Web browser or as a way to navigate through a firewall as the initial connection is an HTTP get.  The latest ActiveMQ broker supports STOMP, MQTT and AMQP over websockets all via that 'ws' based transport connector endpoint.